# How to dynamically adjust Query shape (fields) using Apollo graphql?

Tags: java, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

i want to Query only selected fields using Apollo graphql in java.

Dont find any article which shows how we can achieve that

I define my query in .graphql file like this,

```
query getResources{
   resources(filterBy: {} ) {
      edges{
         cursor
         node   {
                id
                name
                canonicalName
                description
                createdAt
                updatedAt
                createdBy
                updatedBy
         }
      }
      pageInfo{
          hasPreviousPage
          hasNextPage
      }
   }
}
```

while making the query request 
 execute = apolloClient.query(getResourcesQuery).execute();

i want to change the getResourcesQuery object to only query certain fields.
 how can we do that ?

Comment: just remove elements you don't need

Comment: @xadm i want to dynamically change the query

Comment: if i change this query, that would still be static

Comment: why do you need this ?

Comment: @xadm so i am building client sdk for my graphql application, 
while making the query, i want to allow the client to query only the fields it wants

Comment: query is just a string but ... https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag#why-use-this

Comment: It sounds like there's some confusion here... If you want to change the specific fields that the client requests, you'll need to change the query definition you have included in your original post - either build it dynamically in code, or import a template and insert stuff into it, or whatever. It's just string manipulation.

Comment: @kryten i am refering to this example https://github.com/aoudiamoncef/apollo-client-maven-plugin
here i want to specify which fields to query.

Comment: string manipulation is deftinately one way, but i was looking for a way with apollo client to specify that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apollo Android is not really a query builder -- you can't specify individual fields to add to a selection set. Instead, your provided query is sent as-is. If you're looking for that sort of functionality, you may want to look into a different client (like [nodes](https://github.com/americanexpress/nodes)).

That said, you can utilize the `@skip` and `@include` directives, combined with some variables, to dynamically control what's included in your request's selection set. For example:

```
query getResources(
  $includeEdges: Boolean = true
  $includePageInfo: Boolean = true
) {
  resources(filterBy: {}) {
    edges @include(if: $includeEdges) {
      cursor
      node {
        id
        name
        canonicalName
        description
        createdAt
        updatedAt
        createdBy
        updatedBy
      }
    }
    pageInfo @include(if: $includePageInfo) {
      hasPreviousPage
      hasNextPage
    }
  }
}
```

Then just add the variables:

```
GetResources getResourcesQuery = GetResources.builder()
    .includePageInfo(false)
    .build();

apolloClient().query(getResourcesQuery).execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not supported in apollo

https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/issues/1014
[dynamic query graphql apollo with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51608768/dynamic-query-graphql-apollo-with-java)